# Converting Euler angles of object from room's to camera's coordinate system

Tags: image-processing, linear-algebra, trigonometry, euler-angles

I have an object somewhere on the floor of a room and a static camera on the ceiling pointing down directly towards the floor. I know the 3D coordinates of the object and camera, as well as the Euler angles describing the object's orientation/rotation w.r.t. the room:

1. **Azimuth_room (Ar)**: angle between the projection of the object’s main axis onto floor and between the positive x-axis of the room coordinate system.
2. **Pitch_room (Pr)**: angle between the object’s main axis and floor.
3. **Roll_room (Rr)**: object’s rotation around its main axis.

**I want to convert these Euler angles to the camera’s coordinate system (Ac, Pc, Rc) i.e. to describe the object's orientation as seen from the cameras view.**

**Note**: I know there are software packages that can compute this, but I'm interested in the equations and their intuitive explanation. Also, I don't know the exact size of the object.

I think I've managed to figure out the calculation for Pc and Rc (the following are all in the room's coordinate system).

- Denote the point on the arena floor just below the camera “the origin”.
- Define distance_from_origin as the distance between the origin and the object center.
- Define azimuth_from_origin as the orientation of the vector between the origin and the box centroid.
- Define relative_azimuth = object azimuth - azimuth_from_origin
- Define distance_on_main_axis = distance_from_origin * cos(relative_azimuth)
- Define distance_on_trans_axis = distance_from_origin * sin(relative_azimuth)
- Define pitch_angle_adjust = atan(distance_to_main_axis / camera_height)
- Define roll_angle_adjust = atan(distance_to_trans_axis / camera_height)

But I'm not sure this is correct, and I'm still having trouble figuring out Ac.